# Chrome extension that will universally add tooltips to emoji

Tags: chrome, emoji

Emoji are a bit of a pain. Sometimes they're hard to read, sometimes there's no context. I'd like to be able to hover over am emoji and have a tooltip - either of the name of the unicode symbol, shortcode or common name (emojipedia has all these - [for example](https://emojipedia.org/party-popper/) ).  I can't tell if this is a party popper or a taco.

I recall in the past (and I can't find it now) that twitter would add a tooltip when you hovered over an emoji, though that feature is gone with the new UI.

So this is kinda what I need - the ability to hover over an emoji, in modern versions of chrome (I use vivaldi but it shares the chrome app store).